# Error: Invalid JSON object while extracting data from server

Tags: r, json, mongodb

I am trying to run the following Mongodb query in r for extracting data after 2019-08-01 but am getting the error as,

```
Error: Invalid JSON object: {"leadCreatedDate":{"$gt":"ISODate"("2015-08-01T00:00:00.000Z")}}
```

leads is the name of the connection established with the server.

```
all_leads_reg <- leads$find(query = paste0('{"leadCreatedDate":{"$gt":"ISODate"("2015-08-01T00:00:00.000Z")}}'),fields = ('{"leadId":true,"otherInfo.bankDetails.bankId":true}'))
```

Comment: JSON can't encode an `ISODate` object as you seem to be trying to do, so that's indeed not JSON.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt how to solve it then?